# Using Set terminal - See code in one of the variables. What is it?

Tags: environment-variables

When I type set on terminal I see the following. there is code running to a few pages.
Wondering what this is and **how to get rid of it**.

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
_=go
__git_printf_supports_v=yes
_backup_glob='@(#*#|*@(~|.@(bak|orig|rej|swp|dpkg*|rpm@(orig|new|save))))'
_xspecs=([lokalize]="!*.po" [acroread]="!*.[pf]df" [lbzcat]="!*.?(t)bz?(2)"
```

Full code list :
https://pastebin.com/WDWyrKmJ

Comment: `set` is a shell command that is used for setting and showing variables, Typing `set` at its own shows the variables that is set (also called the environment) You cannot "get rid of it". It is a build in command, the system needs it, it works at designed / intended. Just stop writing `set` in the terminal.

Comment: Looks like you didn't follow what I was trying to ask. Please look at the pastebin link till the very end. I am aware of 'set' and what it does. This is source code attached inside one of the env variables. Wondering how it got there and how to get rid of it.